# React: Set background image with props from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I hope I'm asking this question correctly (I'm still green with React).

I am writing a component that will set the background image (from a folder of jpgs) from props of another component.  So let's say the component is "projects" then the background image would be set as "project.jpg" (and component "About" would have a background image of "about.jpg")

I've tried writing this and seems like I get close but not all the way there.  Any React.js Gurus that could help me crack this code would have me singing praises of your screen name

My code

```
    import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const pathToBgImages = require.context('../../../src/static', true);

const bgImages = [
  'about.jpg',
  'blog.jpg',
  'contact.jpg',
  'projects.jpg'
]

const getImages = () => bgImages.map(name => `<img src='${pathToBgImages(name, true)}'/>`);

const BgBackground = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  &::after {
    content: "";
    background: url(${getImages});
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.25;
    height: 400px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
  }
`

class BgImage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
  <BgBackground />
    );
  }
}

export default BgImage;
```

I know there are some blanks in that component and not written correctly, I'm still trying to figure this out.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you getting any error, also i think background: url(${getImages}); should be `background: url(getImages());`

Comment: just a warning:  warning  'getImages' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars